# Google Docs Checkbox Script

Tags: checkbox, google-docs, google-apps, checklistbox

My goal. Count the number of completed tasks out of all tasks, i.e. 46/103 tasks completed. Is it possible to write a script to determine this?
[List in docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiGwp.png)

In the Google documentation there is no isChecked() function, and in the list attributes it is not written whether it is checked :(
[Attributes of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNb2o.png)